# N for a function of several variables

Tags: function-construction, numerical-value

Let

```
Z[1] = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.5, 0.5} -> {0, 1}]
Z[2] = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.6, 0.4} -> {0, 1}]
Z[3] = EmpiricalDistribution[{0.7, 0.3} -> {0, 1}]
```

and

```
F[i_, j_, k_, m_] := 
 Probability[
  Sum[\[Alpha][u], {u, 1, i}] + Sum[\[Beta][u], {u, 1, j}] + 
    Sum[\[Gamma][u], {u, 1, k}] <= m, {Distributed[\[Alpha][1], Z[1]],
    Distributed[\[Alpha][2], Z[1]], Distributed[\[Alpha][3], Z[1]], 
   Distributed[\[Alpha][4], Z[1]], Distributed[\[Alpha][5], Z[1]], 
   Distributed[\[Alpha][6], Z[1]], Distributed[\[Beta][1], Z[2]], 
   Distributed[\[Beta][2], Z[2]], Distributed[\[Beta][3], Z[2]], 
   Distributed[\[Gamma][1], Z[3]], Distributed[\[Gamma][2], Z[3]]}]
```

How to get the values of such function with provided precision?

For example: a command `N[F[6,3,2,0],40]` doesn't give what I want.
In some sense, my function belongs only on m.
Variables i=1,..,6, j=1,..,3 and k=1,..,2 are like a parameters for my function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For N[ _,  40] all inputs must have at least that precision. Your definition of Z[1], Z[2], and z[3] use weights with just machine precision. Rationalize the definitions.

```
Z[1] = EmpiricalDistribution[
    {0.5, 0.5} -> {0, 1}] // Rationalize;
Z[2] = EmpiricalDistribution[
    {0.6, 0.4} -> {0, 1}] // Rationalize;
Z[3] = EmpiricalDistribution[
    {0.7, 0.3} -> {0, 1}] // Rationalize;

F[i_, j_, k_, m_] := 
 Probability[
  Sum[\[Alpha][u], {u, 1, i}] + Sum[\[Beta][u], {u, 1, j}] + 
    Sum[\[Gamma][u], {u, 1, k}] <= m, {Distributed[\[Alpha][1], Z[1]], 
   Distributed[\[Alpha][2], Z[1]], Distributed[\[Alpha][3], Z[1]], 
   Distributed[\[Alpha][4], Z[1]], Distributed[\[Alpha][5], Z[1]], 
   Distributed[\[Alpha][6], Z[1]], Distributed[\[Beta][1], Z[2]], 
   Distributed[\[Beta][2], Z[2]], Distributed[\[Beta][3], Z[2]], 
   Distributed[\[Gamma][1], Z[3]], Distributed[\[Gamma][2], Z[3]]}]

N[F[6, 3, 2, 0], 40]
```

> 0.001653750000000000000000000000000000000000

```
% // Precision
```

> 40.

Since all inputs are exact numbers, you get the resuested precision.

Alternatively,

```
Z[1] = EmpiricalDistribution[
   {0.5`40, 0.5`40} -> {0, 1}];
Z[2] = EmpiricalDistribution[
   {0.6`40, 0.4`40} -> {0, 1}];
Z[3] = EmpiricalDistribution[
   {0.7`40, 0.3`40} -> {0, 1}];

F[i_, j_, k_, m_] := 
 Probability[
  Sum[\[Alpha][u], {u, 1, i}] + Sum[\[Beta][u], {u, 1, j}] + 
    Sum[\[Gamma][u], {u, 1, k}] <= m, {Distributed[\[Alpha][1], Z[1]], 
   Distributed[\[Alpha][2], Z[1]], Distributed[\[Alpha][3], Z[1]], 
   Distributed[\[Alpha][4], Z[1]], Distributed[\[Alpha][5], Z[1]], 
   Distributed[\[Alpha][6], Z[1]], Distributed[\[Beta][1], Z[2]], 
   Distributed[\[Beta][2], Z[2]], Distributed[\[Beta][3], Z[2]], 
   Distributed[\[Gamma][1], Z[3]], Distributed[\[Gamma][2], Z[3]]}]

N[F[6, 3, 2, 0], 40]
```

> 0.00165375000000000000000000000000000000000

```
% // Precision
```

> 38.6576

Note that although the calculation started with inputs of precision 40 there is some loss of precision during the calculations.